# In Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, what happened to the dragon and how did the spectators know that the dragon was defeated?

Tags: harry-potter

In the First Task of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, Harry lures the dragon out of the arena. He then engages the dragon in a tower top duel and eventually causes the dragon to collide with a building. The dragon doesn't return, so Harry returns to the arena on his Firebolt. He is greeted by cheers.

Questions ( based on movie )

What happened to the dragon? Was it killed?

How did the spectators know that Harry had defeated the dragon?

Comment: Is there something in the movie that makes us think the audience believes the dragon had been defeated? I'd be cheering just seeing that the dude was still alive.

Comment: I wonder what they were doing while the dude single handedly fought the dragon

Comment: Harry came back and got the Egg.

Comment: How very odd; the dragon challenge was the only one from the books that the spectators were able to actually see what was happening. For the film to remove that, makes the whole competition even more bizarre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In answer to your question, it depends. In the book, the task was solely to get the egg. The dragon never left the arena. That is the answer if you want the book.

But judging on the context of your question, you are talking about the movie. In the movie, I bet the dragon just flew away (or was handled professionally) and they knew Harry won because he got the Golden Egg. For proof of this, you can google Harry Potter First Task, and go to videos.

Comment: For your actual answer it is extremely speculative. The books part is good but could do with quotes editing in for evidence. The movie part really needs some evidence in it to back it up.

Comment: Yes I talking about the movie.Added it to the question